# Android flip like tab tale

Tags: android, flip

I would love my app to flip like [**Tabtale apps**](http://tabtale.com) when moving to the next activity.

I have played around with page curl, animations, fade in and out.

Is there some sample code or math equation that l could use?

Please help out still new to android.

Answer (score 1):

I think that they are using game engine like cocos2d or something similar and didn't implement it using page curl.